# mysqli update didn't work

Tags: php, mysql

idk where's the wrong part,but the update query didn't work.

this is the form

```
<form method="post">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="ceksetuju" id="cekbox" value="YA" required>
                    <label for="cekbox">dengan ini saya setuju dengan syarat dan ketentuan yang berlaku</label><br>
                    <input type="submit" name="agree" class="button special small" value="Next">
                </form>
```

and this is my php file

```
//CONNECT DATABASE
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '130395', 'dbtest');

//UPDATE TABLE LIRIK
if (isset($_POST['agree'])) {
$id=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_GET['id_lirik']);
$uname=$userRow['user_name'];
$ceksetuju=$_POST['ceksetuju'];
$sqlupdate ="UPDATE lirik set setuju_taken='$ceksetuju',taken_by ='$uname' FROM lirik where id_lirik='$id' ";
$resultupdate = $db->query($sqlupdate);

if ($resultupdate) {
    echo "success";
}
else{
    echo "failed";
   }
}
```

and the result always 'failed'. so, Can somebody tell me what's wrong?

Comment: you should use prepared statements or escale $ceksetuju, too. $_POST-variables can be spoofed very easily, too, so while you've secured $id, your code still is vulnerable for SQL-Injections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for `FROM tablename` in update query. Try with -

```
$sqlupdate = 
"UPDATE lirik set setuju_taken='$ceksetuju',taken_by ='$uname'
 WHERE id_lirik='$id'";
```

**Syntax**

```
UPDATE [table_name]
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2...., columnN = valueN
WHERE [conditions];
```

Comment: Oh my fault. I didn't notice that bfore. now it works well, thank you :) @Sougata

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `FROM` `YOR_TABLE_NAME` in your update query.
You will check your query update or not using `===` operator for more details check this link for operator functionality http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Change your code on this way :

```
$sqlupdate ="UPDATE lirik set setuju_taken='".$ceksetuju."',taken_by ='".$uname."' where id_lirik= $id";
$resultupdate = $db->query($sqlupdate);
if ($resultupdate === TRUE) {
    echo "success";
}
else{
    echo "failed";
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the dots:`$sqlupdate="UPDATE lirik set setuju_taken='".$ceksetuju."',taken_by ='".$uname."' FROM lirik where id_lirik=".$id.";`

NOTE : `taken_by ='".$uname."' VS. id_lirik=".$id."`
I assumed that `taken_by` has a VARCHAR data type and `id_lirik` with an INT data type. There is no need to use FROM `table` in an update query anyway.

Comment: It is nothing to wrong to write $id and '$id'. Both are same if query has double quotes. Refer Sougata's answer. Query should be write by that way.